# Variable unexpectedly resetting to 0 when View Controller Switched

Tags: swift, xcode, variables, xcode6, swift5

I had a variable called "results" in a ViewController called DetailViewController which is given a value, and is printed correctly in FirstViewController:

```
extension FirstViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        
        cell.typeLabel.text = "Name: \(posts[indexPath.row].typeOfFood)"
        cell.titleLabel.text = "Title: \(posts[indexPath.row].title)"
        cell.locationLabel.text = "Location: \(posts[indexPath.row].location)"
        cell.nameLabel.text = "Name: \(posts[indexPath.row].name)"
        return cell
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//        print("Select Row \(indexPath.row)")
        var result = indexPath.row
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
//        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: nil)
        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        guard let detailViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController else{
            print("couldnt find vc")
            return
        }
        let detailVC = DetailViewController()
        detailVC.result = indexPath.row
        print(detailVC.result)
        self.present(detailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }
}
```

But then when my app switches to another ViewController called DetailViewController, The variable result is always printed and stored as 0. DetailViewController:

````
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameOfUserLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var typeOfFoodNeededLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountOfFoodNeededLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var reasonNeededLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageButton: UIButton!
     var posts = [Posts]()
    var rowNumber = String()
    var result = Int()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var rowNumber = Int()
        loadPosts()
print(result)
//        nameOfUserLabel.text = posts[result].name

    }
    
    func loadPosts() {
        Database.database().reference().child("Posts").observe(.childAdded){(snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]{
                
                let titleText = dict["Title"] as! String
                let typeofFoodText = dict["Type of Food"] as! String
                let descriptionText = dict["Description"] as! String
                let amountNeededText = dict["Number of Items Needed"] as! String
                let locationText = dict["Location"] as! String
                let nameText = dict["Name of User"] as! String
                let reasonNeeded = dict["Reason for Donation"] as! String
                
                
                let post = Posts(titleText: titleText, typeOfFoodText: typeofFoodText, descriptionText: descriptionText, amountNeededText: amountNeededText, locationText: locationText, nameText: nameText, reasonNeededText: reasonNeeded)
                 
                self.posts.append(post)
                print(self.posts)

                self.nameOfUserLabel.text = self.posts[self.result].name
                self.descriptionLabel.text = self.posts[self.result].description
                self.typeOfFoodNeededLabel.text = self.posts[self.result].typeOfFood
                self.amountOfFoodNeededLabel.text = self.posts[self.result].amountNeeded
                self.reasonNeededLabel.text = self.posts[self.result].reasonNeeded
                self.locationLabel.text = self.posts[self.result].location

                
                
            }

        }


    }
    ```
````

How can I fix this? I mainly want the value it is given in FirstViewController to carry over to the DetailViewController, but it keeps resetting back to 0.

Comment: `detailVC.result = indexPath.row
 self.present(detailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`, look at this code closely, you are setting `result` on one variable but you are using another one in your `present()` call.

Comment: So what would I have to change in `self.present(detailViewController, animated:true, completion: nil)` ?

Comment: Nothing of course, but you need to set `result` on `detailViewController` and not on the other variable. `detailVC` is completely irrelevant and should be removed.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the result variable to the new instance **detailVC** (detailVC.result) while the right instance for the passed variable is **detailViewController** (detailViewController.result).

Please replace the following in your shared source code:

**This**

```
let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
guard let detailViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController else{
                print("couldnt find vc")
                return
            }
let detailVC = DetailViewController()
detailVC.result = indexPath.row
print(detailVC.result)
self.present(detailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**With**

```
let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    guard let detailViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController else{
                    print("couldnt find vc")
                    return
                }
    detailViewController.result = indexPath.row
    print(detailViewController.result)
    self.present(detailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, please add an explanation of your solution

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I hope you will be happy now ..... :)

Comment: This is only what is expected from a good answer but good for you and hopefully my comments here and above helped you get some points.